# A faster way of loading shapely.wkt geometries into a pandas dataframe from a dataframe of WKT strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shapely, wkt

How it's currently done is as follows:

```
geoms = df["wkt"].apply(shapely.wkt.loads).values
```

Here df["wkt"] has rows with data like:

```
"MULTIPOLYGON (((24.2401805 70.8385222,24.2402333 70.83850555,24.2402166 70.83848885,24.24015 70.83848885,24.2401277 70.83850555,24.2401805 70.8385222)))"
```

But as the dataframe that the function is being applied to is huge this takes a while. Is there a way to speed this up? I've tried looking at multithreading or similar, but didn't really get it to work.

The same applies to this line:

```
df_geoms = [shapely.wkt.loads(x) for x in df.geom.values]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [`from_wkt`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt.html?highlight=wkt) command from the [`GeoPandas`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html) library:

```
geoms = geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df["wkt"])
```